# setting position of many graphic objects in matlab by single command

Tags: matlab

I am an undergraduate student doing my final project of matlab in which I have to set the position of many currently opened graphic objects. I cannot afford to call them separately nor can I call all my handles by using indexing and putting them in a loop. Is there any way to set the position of more than one graphic objects by a command or two or a function that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

The [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) function allows you to enter as input a vector of graphics handles to operate on and combinations of cell arrays, structures, and property/value pairs for property names and values so that you can modify multiple properties on multiple objects in one function call.

For example, let's say you've created 4 sets of axes all stacked one on top of the other:

```
hAxes1 = axes();
title('Axes 1');
hAxes2 = axes();
title('Axes 2');
hAxes3 = axes();
title('Axes 3');
hAxes4 = axes();
title('Axes 4');
```

You can set a new position for each set of axes with one call to [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) as follows:

```
hVector = [hAxes1; hAxes2; hAxes3; hAxes4];  %# Vector of graphics handles
propertyCell = {'Position'};          %# Cell array containing the property name
valueCell = {[0.1 0.6 0.3 0.3]; ...   %# 4-by-1 cell array containing the new
             [0.6 0.6 0.3 0.3]; ...   %#   values for the axes positions
             [0.1 0.1 0.3 0.3]; ...
             [0.6 0.1 0.3 0.3]};
set(hVector,propertyCell,valueCell);  %# Set the new positions
```

And you should see this in your figure window:

[image]